# Linea iOS barcode scan missing first character

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sdk, barcode

I am using a Linea Pro for iPhone 7 with MSR & 2D standard.
I have the issue that the first character in barcodes scanned are missing in an iOS app.
I'm working on an iOS project for the iPhone 7 app. The app uses the Linea SDK:

[image: Linea SDK files]

The scanned barcode is retrieved in the Swift function called:

```
func barcodeData(_ barcode: String!, type: Int32)
```

I could reproduce the issue by scanning different barcodes. When I debug the code in XCode and log the scanned barcode the first character is always missing.

```
func barcodeData(_ barcode: String!, type: Int32) {
    // Prints "ode 128 instead of Code 128"
    print("barcode in barcodeData: \(barcode)")
}
```

I used barcodes from this web site: https://www.datalogic.com/upload/marketlit/demo/r44-2686a.pdf

For example it scans only "ode 128" instead of "Code 128".

Can you maybe help me? Is it a known issue?

Comment: Where would we look at the Linea SDK? And I assume this is a hardware barcode scanner?

Comment: The Linea SDK is currently imported to the project (like in the screenshot in my question). Yes the barcode scanner is an external hardware that you connect the iPhone 7 to.

Comment: @es1 - is the **Linea SDK** open-source? If so, dig into it and debug. If not, pretty sure you need to ask the hardware manufacturer or SDK provider. Unlikely you'll come across someone else here who just happens to have the same hardware and is using the same SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with an iPhone SE running 15.4 and updating the iOS to 15.7.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: Interesting. I updated the Linea SDK to the latest QuantumSDK and that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by downloading the latest QuantumSDK from Linea.
After a month of testing I could not reproduce the issue.
The solution I think is to replace the old Linea SDK with QuantumdSDK.
You can download QuantumSDK from Infinite Peripherals support web site.